# DataTables with Bootstrap - Style Pagination Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a table with DataTables like this: https://jsfiddle.net/scaz23z0/2/

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
  <td>System Architect</td>
  <td>Edinburgh</td>
  <td>61</td>
  <td>2011/04/25</td>
  <td>$320,800</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Garrett Winters</td>
  <td>Accountant</td>
  <td>Tokyo</td>
  <td>63</td>
  <td>2011/07/25</td>
  <td>$170,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ashton Cox</td>
  <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
  <td>San Francisco</td>
  <td>66</td>
  <td>2009/01/12</td>
  <td>$86,000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
  <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
  <td>Edinburgh</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>2012/03/29</td>
  <td>$433,060</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Airi Satou</td>
  <td>Accountant</td>
  <td>Tokyo</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>2008/11/28</td>
  <td>$162,700</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

I'm wondering how I can change the style of the pagination buttons (the ones that say `Previous`,`1` and `Next`) to have another background color for example. I have tried to inspect element to see which CSS class that are affecting them and then trying to edit them, but I haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/cLx7kqgu/1/

The buttons are actually links wrapped inside an `li`named `%table_name%_previous` `%table_name%_next`. You can target them like this.

CSS

```
#example_previous a {
  background-color:black;
}

#example_next a {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: What about the page numbers if I have multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , use important to overwrite bootstrap

```
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span{
  border:1px solid red !important;
}
```